# Instantly type in keyboard using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, rpa, robotjs

I'm currently developing a RPA application. I need to type a text in keyboard, but I need this process to be executed instantly (as if it were a copy and paste).

I've tried Nut.js and Robotjs but both of these have a delay between one key and another even if I configure the delay to 0ms or 1ms.

Someone know another automation library to make this process of typing immediate? Or should I try Python?

Comment: Can you not use those libraries to copy your test to the clipboard then execute a paste?

Comment: @mousetail Yes, I can try this, do you recommend any library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `pyperclip` library to first copy text using the `pyperclip.copy()` function and then use `PyAutoGui` library to paste the text. The pyperclip doesn't have a built-in function to paste but using both of these we can make it work.

Example:

```
import pyperclip
import pyautogui

#copy text to clipboard
text = "Testing the copy and paste"
pyperclip.copy(text)

#paste text from clipboard
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
```

Comment: Many tnx, it worked! Very nice!